# I have no php versions to choose from in drop down cpXstack

Tags: nginx, cpanel, php, whm

After installing cpXstack I want to activate nginx on one of the domains. When I open the cpXstack icon in cPanel, I have an empty drop down, where I should have several PHP versions to choose from.

So I'm stuck and don't know what to do now.

I wonder if anybody knows how to solve this.

Thanks,
Maurice

Answer (score 0):

Today I'm trying to install cpXstack as well, I don't think you need to see the dropdown there, I noticed in /opt/pifpm/scripts the possibility to choose the php version by:

```
toggle_phpfpm.sh username 5.5.14 1
```

however for me it's still not working, still debugging